# Select a column for which another column is maximum

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I'm trying to recreate the following SQLite query in dplyr:

```
SELECT 
  Users.DisplayName, 
  Users.Age, 
  Users.Location, 
  SUM(Posts.FavoriteCount) AS FavoriteTotal, 
  Posts.Title AS MostFavoriteQuestion, 
  MAX(Posts.FavoriteCount) AS MostFavoriteQuestionLikes 
FROM Posts 
JOIN Users 
ON Users.Id=Posts.OwnerUserId 
WHERE Posts.PostTypeId=1 
GROUP BY OwnerUserId 
ORDER BY FavoriteTotal DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see, the query selects the most liked title per user.

In SQLite docs I read that:

> Side note: Bare columns in an aggregate queries. The usual case is that all column names
>   in an aggregate query are either arguments to aggregate functions or else appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause. A result column which contains a column name that is not within an
>   aggregate function and that does not appear in the GROUP BY clause (if one exists) is
>   called a "bare" column.
>
> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query, all bare
>   columns in the result set take values from the input row which also contains the minimum
>   or maximum. So in the query above, the value of the "b" column in the output will be the
>   value of the "b" column in the input row that has the largest "c" value.

So when the engine computes the max value for the user, all you have to do to get his most liked Post is to just write it out in the select.

However, I'm struggling to do the same in dplyr.

That's what I have so far:

```
Posts %>% 
  inner_join(Users, by = c("OwnerUserId" = "Id")) %>%
  filter(PostTypeId==1) %>% 
  group_by(OwnerUserId, DisplayName, Age, Location) %>% 
  summarise(FavoriteTotal = sum(FavoriteCount), MostFavoriteQuestionLikes = max(FavoriteCount))%>% 
  arrange(desc(FavoriteTotal))
```

The problem is that `summarise` returns a table whose only columns are the summarised ones and the grouped ones. This table does not have any reference to a PostId, so I have no idea how to access it. It only has the reference to a user.

How can I get the Post.Title that I'm looking for in dplyr?

What I'd like to get is a table that:
1) has the user
2) has the sum of all FavoriteCount of all the Posts written by this user
3) has the maximum value of FavoriteCount for this user
4) has the Title of the Post that has this maximum FavoriteCount written by this user

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a grouped transformation without aggregating the data frame you simply use mutate instead of summarise like this:

```
Posts %>% 
  inner_join(Users, by = c("OwnerUserId" = "Id")) %>%
  filter(PostTypeId==1) %>% 
  group_by(OwnerUserId, DisplayName, Age, Location) %>% 
  mutate(FavoriteTotal = sum(FavoriteCount), MostFavoriteQuestionLikes = max(FavoriteCount))%>% 
  arrange(desc(FavoriteTotal))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using `mutate` does compute something, but not exactly what I'm after. Right now the result table that technically is grouped by the user, but because one user can write many posts, there are multiple rows for each user. I've edited the question a bit to better reflect what I'm after.

Comment: @FilipBarankiewicz then to further help please follow Edwards advice and post the output of ```dput()``` so we can test the code at home.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)
Posts %>% 
  inner_join(Users, by = c("OwnerUserId" = "Id")) %>%
  filter(PostTypeId==1) %>% 
  group_by(OwnerUserId, DisplayName, Age, Location) %>% 
  summarise(FavoriteTotal = sum(FavoriteCount), 
            MostFavoriteQuestionLikes = max(FavoriteCount),
            MostFavoriteQuestion = unique(PostsTypeId)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(FavoriteTotal)) %>% 
  top_n(10)
```